# Where to put custom function in Joomla

Tags: php, function, joomla, joomla1.5

I want to create some function for rendering images from within Joomla v1.5.23. That function should be visible through all joomla application.

Where I have to put that function? Should I create plug in, modul or something else?

Best regards

Comment: What version are you working with?

Comment: joomla version is 1.5.23

Comment: Then my answer below should work just fine.  We've done what you're trying to do - when the plugin is fired, it creates a custom object which we access throughout the site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version info would be helpful, but I believe your answer is to create a plugin.  Components are very broad "mini applications" installed and executed within Joomla.  Modules are typically pieces of code that display information from a component, or an outside source.  Plugins have various places within Joomla, depending on what they do - like authentication, or admin, etc.  You'll have to define what role the plugin will play to determine where it fits into that hierarchy.  Once done though, the plugin will be loaded, and you'll be able to access it's functions from within Joomla.

This link will show you how to begin by [writing a content plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_content_plugin).  Note the events that are available.  This isn't too difficult to do, so don't overcomplicate it, and you should be fine.  An example of a System Plugin (which sounds like what you're looking for) can be seen at http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System.

Comment: Good luck with it...as I say, i'ts not difficult, and there are plenty of examples at JED to look at if you get stuck on how to accomplish something

Comment: Can you please tell me what is JED?